# Select box Cause infinite loop when used with ng-template recursion

Tags: javascript, html, angular, dom, recursion

I'm trying to do a recursion here  and when anything expects select box and input box it works 
but with a select box here it gives

> ERROR RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

anyone have an idea why and how to fix it?

```
<ul> 
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="recursiveList; context:myContext"></ng-container>
<ng-template #recursiveList let-list>
<li *ngFor="let f of list">
   <div class="added-FE property" >   
      <dx-select-box [dataSource]="widget.Fields" displayExpr="name" valueExpr="name" [(value)]="f.opnet" placeholder="select property"></dx-select-box
   </div>
   <ul class="ulList" *ngIf="f  && f.supList.length > 0">
      <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="recursiveList; context:get(f)"></ng-container>
   </ul>
</li> 
</ng-template> 
</ul>
```

get(f) return list equal to f.sublist
myContext returns list contain one element which is the root

Comment: Please create reproduction. What is the `get(f)`?

Comment: get(f) return list equal to f.sublist